# how to get json object from HttpEntity?

Tags: java, http, json

I have an HttpEntity object created as below:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(new URI(currentUrl));
HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(get);
HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();
String respbody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(respbody);
```

Result:
org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 2

Observation:
respbody string when printed is not the same text returned from currentUrl, it includes some non ascii characters.
I tried adding charset to tostring method but no luck!
It will be very helpful if anyone can suggest why this string is not normal text?

Comment: Print out `respbody`? Show us an example.

Comment: @gnat - Gee thanks!  User -- do as Sotirios says and print out `respbody`.  Compare it to the syntax of JSON you'll find at json.org.  Then come back and explain to us what it means.